# .NET SMTP Mail - Attachment File Name being renamed

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

**Desired Approach:**

I want to keep the same file name when sending the file as an attachment and not have .NET rename it (for whatever reason it's adding on the path to the file). **I do not want to have to pass another param to set the file name.**

**Example:**

```
- Project (folder)
 - Content (folder)
  - Files (folder)
   - PDF (folder)
    - Triumeq (folder)
     - sample.pdf (file)
```

The file name in the attachment on the email is always renamed to:

`DOMAINcontentfilespdftriumeqsample.pdf`

DOMAIN = marked out in image

[image]

**Things I've tried:**

```
// add attachment if applicable
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilePath))
{
    var fs = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, attachmentFilePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fs, fs.Name, MimeTypesHelper.GetContentType(Path.GetExtension(fs.Name))));

   // MimeTypeHelper.GetContentType just returns the MimeType of the file listed in the file stream
}
```

**OR**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilePath))
{
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, attachmentFilePath)));
}
```

Each way always renames the file, and doesn't keep the original file name

Comment: Have you tried using backslashes, i.e. "content\files\pdf\sample.pdf"?

Comment: @CodeFuller Just tried, didn't work. Also used double slashes `//` and `\\\`, but to no avail. Good thought though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachment constructor you use expects value of `Name` property for Mime ContentType as second argument. When you pass string with slashes they are just removed as not-allowed characters.

You will not be able to have some path in file attachment name, only pure file name is allowed. So you should extract filename from the path, e.g.:

```
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fs, Path.GetFileName(fs.Name), MimeTypesHelper.GetContentType(Path.GetExtension(fs.Name))));
```

This will make attachment name to be 'sample.pdf'.

Comment: Nice! I even looked at a post about that, must have missed it. Good lookin' out!